# Kunena forum shortcut not displayed correctly in joomla horizontal menu

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, kunena

I try to add a kunena (a popular joomla forum extension) shortcut in joomla horizontal menu (protostar template/position-1).

Kunena automatically created a menu entry during installation.

[image]

Kunena top url is `<host>/index.php/forum`. And this url seems fishy to me already (the index.php part).

I have 2 items in main menu (the horizontal menu) : "accueil" (home in french) and "forum".

[image]

When I select "accueil", the menu item is highlighted.

[image]

But when I select "forum", the menu item is **not** hightlighted

[image]

My questions:

- What did I do wrong to have my menu item not highlighted? (if I add a random internal link in horizontal menu, `<host>/index.php/2014-07-24-14-11-04` for example, it is highlighted correctly)
- Is it a normal behavior to  get an "index.php" in the middle of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight issue seem to be more css problem and not joomla.
If you move the kunena button from the subcategory to the top menu does it get highlighted?

As for index.php you have to rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess to your ftp directory and enable sef url from joomla global configuration:

> System -> Global configuration -> Search Engine Friendly URLs
>
> System -> Global configuration -> Use URL rewriting

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by moving kunena button from the subcategory to the top menu. I'm not able to select the kunena top menu, only its subcategories.

Comment: Please try to disable all kunena menu buttons to see if highlight issue gets fixed.

Comment: It worked when I disabled all kunena subcategory, thank you. And .htaccess + "use url rewriting" is working too but I still have some apache configuration to do since now, I get mostly 404 errors.

Comment: Well, no luck for now. I cleared my cache, switched to another browser, purged anything I could find in administrator cache menus, restarted apache2, commented out `Options +FollowSymLinks` as stated in .htaccess

Comment: hm.. seem like a server problem. Are you sure that it's the default joomla .htaccess without any customizations inside?

Comment: Yes, it's the default joomla .htaccess. I just updated to joomla 3.3.2 today and it's still the same htaccess.txt. Maybe it has something to do with my apache config files. I think everything is by default, except the file I added for this project, containing a single line : `Alias /mysite /home/me/projects/project1/www`